# Analysing app data in bigquery from google play store on partitioned tables

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, google-play-developer-api

I was able to connect my google play store data to big query via transfer service. Now I have a lot of data about my app.

I have already done the `sentiment analysis and topic modelling` on it.

but it still has data about ratings, installs, and crashes (app version, device, os version, carrier, country, language and so on)`

I would like to merge these different tables that are available in the screenshot below and analyze the data.

[image]

To begin with, for example, I would like to analyse for example `p_Crashes_device_PS`which has columns

```
**Filed name**     **Type**  
Date                 DATE   
Package_Name       STRING               
Device             STRING               
Daily_Crashes     INTEGER               
Daily_ANRs        INTEGER
```

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) AS Year,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) AS Month,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(Device, r'^(\w+)') AS Device,
  SUM(Daily_Crashes) AS Total_Crashes,
  SUM(Daily_ANRs) AS Total_ANRs
FROM
 `abc.google_playstore.p_Crashes_device_PS`
GROUP BY
  Year, Month, Device
ORDER BY
  Year, Month, Device
```

Now I can see that one device had most of the crashes, but what I am missing is how to connect this data with other tables to be sure of what went wrong and in which country/language/os/app/carrier etc

To my surprise, I could not find a single article that helps me understand these Play Store dataset tables and analyse this data in the big query/python.

Am I doing something wrong? There are Google apps data analysis but it involves comparing different apps etc not related to a single app and its specific data.

I would be very happy if someone can push me in the right direction where I can find this analysis. Thank you

Comment: You can check the details of each report and column description here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/play-transformation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JOIN clause to combine two or more tables based on a related column between them. For example, if you want to join the p_Crashes_device_PS table with another table that has information about app versions, you can use the following query:  
`` SELECT * FROM `abc.google_playstore.p_Crashes_device_PS` AS crashes JOIN `abc.google_playstore.app_version_PS` AS versions ON crashes.Package_Name = versions.Package_Name ``
This query will return all columns from both tables where the Package_Name column matches between them. You can add more JOIN clauses to combine more tables based on related columns. You can learn more about joins in BigQuery [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join_types)

Comment: Dear @joevanie, thanks but the question is not about SQL statements but rather about specific underlying details on Play Store data. Thank you!